# Is there a way to automatically fit the TextView scale x to the view?

Tags: textview

If the width of the set view is exceeded when the value of the TextView is changed,
is there a way to automatically adjust the scale X of the text so that it is fully displayed in the view?

Comment: Try [autosizing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.